# What kind of sentence structure is this? "The true measure of our character is ..."

Tags: syntactic-analysis, sentence

> The true measure of our character is how we treat the poor, the disfavored, the accused, and the incarcerated.

I don't know what type of sentence this is. If any of you know please answer! Complex? simple? compound? Anything else it could be.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple sentence of the form SVC (SVC<sub>*s*</sub>) where the SVC elements are as follows.

- S (subject): *the true measure of our character*
- V (verb):   *is*
- C<sub>*s*</sub> (subject complement): *how we treat the poor, the disfavored, the accused, and the incarcerated*

The subject is a noun phrase, the verb is a copula, and the subject complement is a clause, but it is not a subordinate clause, so the sentence is not a complex sentence. It is a nominal relative clause.

> (CoGEL § **15.8**) Nominal relative clauses
> 15.8 Nominal relative clauses resemble wh-interrogative clauses (cf 15.5) in that
> they are also introduced by a wh-element. Indeed, a major reason for
> including nominal relative clauses in this chapter is that it is often difficult to
> distinguish them from the interrogative clauses.
> On the other hand, in some respects nominal relative clauses are more like
> noun phrases, since they can be concrete as well as abstract and can refer
> even to persons. In fact, we can paraphrase them by noun phrases containing
> a noun head with general reference that is modified by a relative clause:
>
> ♦ That's *how she works*. [' . . . the way (that) she works.']
> ♦ That's *how long it takes*. [' . . . the length of time (that) it takes.']
> ♦ This is *how big it was*. [' . . . the size (that) it was.']
> ♦ That's *why I don't go there anymore*. [' . . . the reason (that) I don't go
> there anymore.']
>
> Nominal relative clauses have the same range of functions as noun phrases.
> In addition to the functions available generally to nominal clauses, they can
> function as indirect object and object complement:
> **subject**: *What I want* is a cup of hot cocoa.
> **direct object**: You should see *whoever deals with complaints*.
> **indirect object**: He gave *whoever asked for it* a copy of his latest paper.
> **subject complement**: April is *when the lilacs bloom*.
> **object complement**: You can call me what(euer) you like.
> **appositive**: I'll pay you the whole debt: *what I originally borrowed and what
> I owe you in interest*.
> **prepositional complement**: You should vote for *which(ever) candidate you
> think best*.